# Error: non-declaration statement outside function body on redisstor

Tags: session, go, redis

Follow redisstor [docs](https://github.com/boj/redistore), I'd like to modify [this](https://github.com/josephspurrier/gowebapp/blob/master/vendor/app/shared/session/session.go) code to use redis to store sessions. Here is what I came up with:

```
package session

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
    redisStore "gopkg.in/boj/redistore.v1"
)
var store *redisStore.RediStore
var Name string
var err error

store, err = redisStore.NewRediStore(10, "tcp", ":6379", "", []byte("secret-key"))
if err != nil  {
  log.Fatal("error getting redis store : ", err)
}
defer store.Close()

// Session stores session level information
type Session struct {
    Options   sessions.Options `json:"Options"`   
    Name      string           `json:"Name"`      
    SecretKey string           `json:"SecretKey"` 
}

// Configure the session cookie store
func Configure(s Session) {
    Store := store
    Store.Options = &s.Options
    Name = s.Name
}

// Instance returns a new session, never returns an error
func Instance(r *http.Request) *sessions.Session {
session, _ := Store.Get(r, Name)
return session
 }
```

But I get this error:

```
vendor/app/shared/session/session.go:19:1: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
```

I'm wondering what is wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: The [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/) should answer most basic syntax questions about the language.

Comment: Why don't you open the redis store inside `Configure` just like the original code does with the session store? Also do not close the store if you want your session-related code to actually keep working.

Comment: @mkopriva when I put `store, err = redisStore.NewRediStore(10, "tcp", ":6379", "", []byte("secret-key"))` inside `Configure`, I still get the same error.

Comment: @grhn well then you have more "non-declaration statements outside function body" in your code then you've shown us in the example.

Comment: @mkopriva you are right. I forgot to remove the original one. But now I get `undefined: Store` error at `session, _ := Store.Get(r, Name)`

Comment: Do not remove [this line](https://github.com/josephspurrier/gowebapp/blob/master/vendor/app/shared/session/session.go#L11) just change the type from `*session.CookieStore` to `*redisStore.RediStore`.

Comment: When I remove `var store *redisStore.RediStore` and use `var Store *sessions.CookieStore` instead, I get `store undefined` at `store, err = redisStore.NewRediStore(10,...`

Comment: What do you need `store` for if you have `Store`? Also in the previous comment I mentioned you need to change the types to make it work.

Comment: When I use `var Store *redisStore.RediStore` I still get `store undefined` at `store, err = redisStore.NewRediStore(10, "tcp", ":6379", "", ...` Please tell me what exactly should I put into `Configure`.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/GsY3WtnWhuJ

Comment: @mkopriva this works great. Thank you! Please answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the offending code inside the `Configure` function to replace the original that initializes the `CookieStore`.

```
var (
    // Store is the *redis* store
    Store *redisStore.RediStore
    // Name is the session name
    Name string
)

// ...

// Configure the session cookie store
func Configure(s Session) {
    var err error
    Store, err = redisStore.NewRediStore(10, "tcp", ":6379", "", []byte("secret-key"))
    if err != nil  {
        log.Fatal("error getting redis store : ", err)
    }

    Store.Options = &s.Options
    Name = s.Name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
store, err = redisStore.NewRediStore(10, "tcp", ":6379", "", []byte("secret-key"))
if err != nil  {
  log.Fatal("error getting redis store : ", err)
}
defer store.Close()
```

are non declaration statements. This must reside inside a function. For example `init()` or `main()` functions.

Comment: Well, as you can see I have to put `store`  in `package session` in order to integrate it itno `gowebapp`.  The problem is how to do so?

Comment: You can do store initialization in package session init() function. This special kind of function documented in language specification

Comment: Isn't there a way to put the `store` inside `package session`? After all, it is called by `main()`, as you can see here: https://github.com/josephspurrier/gowebapp/blob/master/gowebapp.go